# How to add options function code for pine script?

Tags: pine-script

How to add options choice for this code for pine script?

instead of this code :

```
distance = input.int(250, 'Time range', minval=5, step=10)
```

to :

```
distance = input.string(defval = '100', title = 'distance', options = ['100', '200', '300' , '500'], group = 'Settings')
```

To make supports and resistances by selecting "Time Range" "Sensitivity"

as you see it at picture:

[image]

[image]

I think the indicator already there at tradingview but i don't find it..

```html
//@version=5
indicator('Classic_Levels', overlay=true)
// number of candles used
distance = input.int(250, 'Time range', minval=5, step=10)
// sensitivity when searching levels
sensitivity = input.float(1, 'Sensitivity', minval=0.1, step=0.1)
// weight coefficients
float wOpenClose = 1
float wHighLow = 0.5
float wCross = 0.5
// number of intervals
int n_intervals = 300
// block size (in intervals)
int block_size = 11


// minimum and maximum values
float min_value = barstate.islast ? low[-ta.lowestbars(distance)] : 0
float max_value = barstate.islast ? high[-ta.highestbars(distance)] : 0

// recalculate sensitivity according to the weights
float sens = barstate.islast ? 2 / (sensitivity * (wOpenClose + wHighLow + wCross)) : 0

// calculate everything on the last bar
if barstate.islast
    // number of "key points" falling into each interval
    // last element is stored but not used
    m = array.new_int(n_intervals + 1, 0)
    // sum of the "scores" of the points falling into each interval
    // last element is stored but not used
    r = array.new_float(n_intervals + 1, 0)
    // sums of the interval forming the block
    a = array.new_float(block_size, 0)

    // declaring variables
    int i_close = na
    int i_open = na
    int i_high = na
    int i_low = na
    int mn = na
    int mx = na
    float interval_size = (max_value - min_value) / float(n_intervals)

    // populate arrays r, m 
    for k = 1 to distance - 1 by 1
        i_close := math.floor((close[k] - min_value) / interval_size)
        i_open := math.floor((open[k] - min_value) / interval_size)
        i_high := math.floor((high[k] - min_value) / interval_size)
        i_low := math.floor((low[k] - min_value) / interval_size)
        array.set(r, i_close, array.get(r, i_close) + wOpenClose)
        array.set(r, i_open, array.get(r, i_open) + wOpenClose)
        array.set(r, i_high, array.get(r, i_high) + wHighLow)
        array.set(r, i_low, array.get(r, i_low) + wHighLow)
        array.set(m, i_close, array.get(m, i_close) + 1)
        array.set(m, i_open, array.get(m, i_open) + 1)
        array.set(m, i_high, array.get(m, i_high) + 1)
        array.set(m, i_low, array.get(m, i_low) + 1)
        // if current candle crosses the interval
        if math.abs(i_open - i_close) >= 2
            mn := math.min(i_open, i_close)
            mx := math.max(i_open, i_close)
            for i = mn + 1 to mx - 1 by 1
                array.set(r, i, array.get(r, i) - wCross)
                array.set(m, i, array.get(m, i) + 1)

    // current block sum
    float cur_block = 0
    // last extremum
    float extr_block = 0
    // number of the first interval of extremum block
    int extr_val = 0
    // level value
    float level_val = 0
    // initial state: level search
    bool state = false
    // current interval sum
    float cur_sum = 0
    // iterate intervals
    for i = 0 to n_intervals + block_size - 2 by 1
        // shift all the interval sums
        array.shift(a)
        if i < n_intervals
            array.push(a, array.get(r, i) / array.get(m, i))
        else
            array.push(a, 0)
        // current block sum
        cur_block := array.sum(a)
        // check state
        if not state
            // searching level: <extr_block> keeps the last maximum
            if i == 0 or cur_block > extr_block
                extr_block := cur_block
                extr_val := i - block_size + 1
                extr_val
            else
                // if we've gone far enough from the maximum downwards
                if extr_block - cur_block >= sens or i == n_intervals - 1
                    // draw level
                    level_val := min_value + interval_size * (extr_val + float(block_size) / 2)
                    line.new(bar_index - 1, level_val, bar_index, level_val, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.both, color=color.blue, width=1)
                    extr_block := cur_block
                    extr_val := i - block_size + 1
                    state := true
                    state
        else
            // level is found: <extr_block> keeps the last minimum
            if cur_block < extr_block
                extr_block := cur_block
                extr_val := i - block_size + 1
                extr_val
            else
                // if we've gone far enough from the minimum upwards
                if cur_block - extr_block >= sens
                    extr_block := cur_block
                    extr_val := i - block_size + 1
                    state := false
                    state
plotshape(barstate.islast, style=shape.circle, color=color.new(color.navy, 0), size=size.tiny, offset=-distance)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. It looks like you already know how to use `input.string` with `options` argument. Where exactly do you need help?

Comment: if you try to run this script coming this wrong massge    4:59:11 PM — Compilation error. Line 5: Cannot call 'input.float' with argument 'defval'='100'. An argument of 'literal string' type was used but a 'const float' is expected
line 5: Cannot call 'input.float' with argument 'options'='100,150,200,250,450,750,1000'. An argument of '[literal string, literal string, literal string, literal string, literal string, literal string, literal string]' type was used but a '[const float...]' is expected
line 55: The end value of the "for" loop must be a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input.string` will return a `string` even if you only use numbers.

So, you need to cast your string to a number type. You can use `str.tonumber()` for that. It will return a `float`. If you need an `int`, you need to cast the return value of `str.tonumber()` to `int`.

```
in_distance = input.string(defval = '100', title = 'distance', options = ['100', '200', '300' , '500'], group = 'Settings')
distance_float = str.tonumber(in_distance)  // This will return a float
distance_int = int(distance_float)  // This will return an int
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove minval and step.

For example

```
distance = input.int(250, 'Time range',  options=[250,500,1000])
```

Explanation:
No need to paas minval, maxval and step, If  you are using options

You can do same thing with `input.float()`

[image]

Comment: thanks can you help me to add price for support and resistance